# PySpark look up value in nested dictionary

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe and I want to look up values in a nested dictionary. Say the df looks like this:

```
data = [
    {"foo": "foo1", "buzz": "buzz1"},
    {"foo": "foo2", "buzz": "buzz1"},
    {"foo": "foo1", "buzz": "buzz2"},
    {"foo": "foo2", "buzz": "buzz2"},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in data)
df.show()
+-----+----+
| buzz| foo|
+-----+----+
|buzz1|foo1|
|buzz1|foo2|
|buzz2|foo1|
|buzz2|foo2|
+-----+----+
```

and a dictionary that looks like this:

```
mapping = {
    "buzz1": {"foo1": "oneone", "foo2": "onetwo"},
    "buzz2": {"foo1": "twoone", "foo2": "twotwo"},
}
```

How do I look up the values inside the nested mapping using the buzz column and then the foo column to create the following data frame:

```
+-----+----+------+
| buzz| foo| combo|
+-----+----+------+
|buzz1|foo1|oneone|
|buzz1|foo2|onetwo|
|buzz2|foo1|twoone|
|buzz2|foo2|twotwo|
+-----+----+------+
```

Comment: show us the code...

Answer (score 1):

here's a quite "hacky" way of achieving the output.

- I first create `when` statements for each mapping individually using a list comprehension
- and then use a `coalesce` to merge them

```py
# separate case whens for each mapping
indv_whens = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, 
                    [[func.when((func.col('buzz') == k) & (func.col('foo') == k1), func.lit(v1)) for k1, v1 in v.items()] 
                     for k, v in mapping.items()]
                    )

# [Column<'CASE WHEN ((buzz = buzz1) AND (foo = foo1)) THEN oneone END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN ((buzz = buzz1) AND (foo = foo2)) THEN onetwo END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN ((buzz = buzz2) AND (foo = foo1)) THEN twoone END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN ((buzz = buzz2) AND (foo = foo2)) THEN twotwo END'>]

# actual usage in dataframe
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('combo', func.coalesce(*indv_whens)). \
    show()

# +----+-----+------+
# | foo| buzz| combo|
# +----+-----+------+
# |foo1|buzz1|oneone|
# |foo2|buzz1|onetwo|
# |foo1|buzz2|twoone|
# |foo2|buzz2|twotwo|
# +----+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to flatten your nested dictionary in a structure that can be directly transformed into a `DataFrame`

#### Flatten Dictionary

```
mapping = {
    "buzz1": {"foo1": "oneone", "foo2": "onetwo"},
    "buzz2": {"foo1": "twoone", "foo2": "twotwo"},
}

rows = []
for key1 in mapping:
    for key2 in mapping[key1]: 
        row = (key1,key2, mapping[key1][key2])
        rows.append(row)

print(rows)

[('buzz1', 'foo1', 'oneone'), ('buzz1', 'foo2', 'onetwo'), ('buzz2', 'foo1', 'twoone'), ('buzz2', 'foo2', 'twotwo')]
```

#### Data Generation

```
sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(rows,['foo','buzz','combo'])

sparkDF.show()

+-----+----+------+
|  foo|buzz| combo|
+-----+----+------+
|buzz1|foo1|oneone|
|buzz1|foo2|onetwo|
|buzz2|foo1|twoone|
|buzz2|foo2|twotwo|
+-----+----+------+
```